# Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data

Tags: php, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom, phantomjs, laravel

I get this error

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

in my PHP functions if I do not do an `echo` followed by a `flush()`. In these functions where I have to do the `echo` and `flush()`, I am using `shell_exec()` to run `phantomjs` and processing the result returned by it using `simple_html_dom`. I am also using a PHP framework called Laravel.

What cause this error, and why does `echo`ing and doing a `flush()` fix this error?

Comment: What versions of the software?

Comment: phantomjs 1.6.1, PHP 5.3.1.5, Laravel 3.2.5, simple_html_dom 1.5

Comment: Do you have read + write permission set correctly on the `storage` folder?This is required for external Cache file

Comment: Do you preparing response in very long period of time with `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` ? I'm also encountered this issue in new version of Chrome, but Internet Explorer works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, Laravel expects output to be `return`ed by your route or controller, not `echo`ed.  As an example, you might have

```
Route::get('foo', function() {
    return 'Hi';
});
```

Laravel will then output 'Hi' to the browser.  Depending on your needs, you can either build this output yourself or make use of Laravel's [View or Response](http://laravel.com/docs/views) classes to format the data in a way that is appropriate for your app.

If you absolutely *need* to flush output using echo, here's one possible way to [do it through a view file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790844/php-flush-doesnt-work-with-laravel).