# PHP flush() doesn't work with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel and I need to output data as it happens. When I attempt to load the page outside Laravel, it works just fine. If I use this inside Laravel, it doesn't flush, it waits until the end and prints the results.

**view.php**

```
<?php

if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){

    echo "<br> Line to show. $i";
    echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";    

    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);

}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: php has never been good at this - and was never really designed for it, being server-side, have you considered another approach

Comment: Like most frameworks the output from the views are contained within ob_*() calls to allow for features such as compression, better error handling, and setting HTTP headers after data has been printed. After all that is done it then will output the data. So putting your own ob_*() call will not break out of the outer one.

Comment: so what options do i have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out, I needed to add ob_flush();

Answer (score 1):

Update, for anyone coming here.

The above solutions didn't work for me. What worked, is adding the

`header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');`

before any output.

Found it here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/live-output-in-blade-template-ob-flush

Answer (score 0):

This sequence worked for me.

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
echo "Processing ... "; // Or give out JSON output
ob_flush();
sleep(5); //A time-consuming synchronous process (SMTP mail, maybe?)
echo "Done";
```